# Core Data initialisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm new to coredata so I have very basic question
I have the Providers entity, in my view controller at the viewDidLoad i implement this method:

```
-(NSDictionary *) allProviders {
    Providers *orangeFR = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Providers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    orangeFR.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Orange"];
    orangeFR.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Champ De Mars"];
    Providers *sfrFR = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Providers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    sfrFR.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SFR"];
    sfrFR.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SFR Adress"];
    NSArray *FRProviders = @[orangeFR, sfrFR];

    Providers *ATT = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Providers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    BeelineRU.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATT"];
    BeelineRU.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATT adress"];
    Providers *Verizon = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Providers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    MTSRU.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Verizon"];
    MTSRU.adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Verizon Adress"];
    NSArray *USProviders = @[ATT, Verizon];


    _allProviders = @{@"France": FRProviders, @"USA":USProviders};
    return _allProviders;
}
```

So everything works fine, but at second launch of the application I need to check if there's already filled my Provider entity. How to do that, so I could get my _allProviders in both case?

Comment: I know I have to use fetchrequest but how can I get my allProviders organised this way if with `executeFetchRequest:` I will get the whole Providers entity?

Comment: Note: your entity should have been named `Provider` instead of `Providers`. Entity names are supposed to be singular, never plural. Entities describe a type of database record, not a table of database records.

Comment: Is the Providers data of a type that is only loaded once on first use of your app by the user? In that sense is required for your app to function correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *providersByCountry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
```

Fetch all the entities:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Providers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSArray *providers = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

Insert your providers into the dictionary (I'm assuming you have a `country` property on your `Providers` entity... does it have one?):

```
for (Providers *provider in providers) {
    NSArray *providersForThisCountry = [providersByCountry[provider.country]
    if (!providersForThisCountry) {
        providersForThisCountry = [NSArray array];
    }

    providersForThisCountry = [providersForThisCountry arrayByAddingObject:provider];

    providersByCountry[provider.country] = providersForThisCountry;
}
```

Finally, make an immutable copy of the `NSMutableDictionary`, and return it:

```
return providersByCountry.copy;
```

Since this is potentially a fairly slow operation, you might want to cache the result in a private `@property` — but you'll need to clear the cache somehow whenever you modify the provider list.

Comment: I dont have country property in my Providers entity, I just use manually countries as a keys in my allProviders dictionary

Comment: @dav well if you want to use core data to build allProviders you have to store the country in core data.

Comment: Do I have to store countries in another entity or I can use it in my Providers? I use countries in tableview, so I don't need it to be displayed more than one time

Comment: I would just add a `country` property, as a string, to your existing provider entity. That will work with the code i posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* allProviders = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Providers"] error:nil];
```